# Command Not Found with Dockerfile CMD

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that uses

```
CMD ['/usr/local/bin/gunicorn', '-b 0.0.0.0:8000', 'myapp.wsgi']
```

But when I run the container using `docker run --rm myimage:latest` I get an error:

> /bin/sh: 1: [/usr/local/bin/gunicorn,: not found

Yet, when I run `docker run --rm -it myimage:latest /bin/bash` to go into the container, I can see that gunicorn runs, and running `which gunicorn` returns the correct path for gunicorn.  Why is it failing to run?

Similarly, I planned on adding

```
ENTRYPOINT ['/entrypoint.sh']
```

to my Dockerfile, but when I run that, I get the error

> /bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: [/entrypoint.sh]: not found

The `entrypoint.sh` file contains:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo 'Starting app...'
cd /app || exit;
python manage.py migrate;
```

So why does it keep saying command not found when all the commands are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the **quotes**. Use double `"`  quotes.

From [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use
>   double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).

This is applicable for other instructions such as RUN, LABEL, ENV, ENTRYPOINT and VOLUME.